# Cannot connect to sql datebase using nuget package manager console

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Hello I am a beginner in web application development. I am creating a database using nuget package manager console however it gives the following error:

```
Error Number:-1983577849,State:0,Class:20
```

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

(provider: `SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.`)

Comment: Have you made sure the sql server is up and running?

Comment: Yes it seems to be running as I see a green 'play' symbol on SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: It would be better to add your code that you use to your question so people could help better https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Check the connection string (that you have not provide here)